# X Display on Windows machine

Tags: windows, system, putty, environment, displaytag

I'm trying to run some code on the server through PuTTY on a windows machine, and it doesn't work. (It works on Linus and Mac)

And I'm pretty sure it is the problem of X display.

Can anyone tell me how to setup the X environment on Windows?

Comment: This is not a programming question so should really be directed at superuser.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to have an X server on Windows is to use [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net): this tool will allow you to connect to your server just like PuTTY does, but it will display your remote graphical applications on your Windows computer using its embedded X server.

You can download the free edition here: http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download-home-edition.html

Answer (score 0):

Putty doesn't support X display.
You can use RealVNC.
You can download it from: https://www.realvnc.com/